# inputing data in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I created a simple form in codeigniter to insert 4 items into mysql.  isbn, author, price, title.
When I click on submit it tells me book/book_validation  404 page not found.  I tried everything I don't know whats wrong.  My database and config file is all correct.

Here is my code

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Book extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->view('insert_book');
    }


    public function book_validation() {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('isbn', 'ISBN', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            echo "Every value has been accepted";
            $this->load->model("model_books");
            $this->insert();
    }



}


        public function insert() {
        $newRow = array("isbn" => $this->input->post('isbn'),
                        "author" => $this->input->post('author'),
                        "price" => $this->input->post('price'),
                        "title" => $this->input->post('title'),

        );

        $this->get_db->insert1($newRow);
        echo "Item added ";

        }









}

?>


    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Book Database</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Book Database</h1>

    <?php



        echo form_open('book/book_validation');


        echo "<p>ISBN ";
        echo form_input('isbn');
        echo "</p>";

        echo "<p>Author: ";
        echo form_input('author');
        echo "</p>";

        echo "<p>Price: ";
        echo form_input('price');
        echo "</p>";

        echo "<p>Title: ";
        echo form_input('title');
        echo "</p>";


        echo "<p> ";
        echo form_submit('submit', 'Insert Book');
        echo "</p>";


        echo form_close();
    ?>



    </body>

</html> 

    <?php

class Model_books extends CI_Model {

    public function insert1($data) {


        $this->db->insert("books", $data);

        /*
        if($result) {
            echo $this->db->affected_rows() . "books inserted into database ";
        }

        else {
            echo "Book not added ";
        }
        */
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: And does the link `book/book_validation` seem valid to you?

Comment: @BackinaFlash if you refer to form_open('book/book_validation') yeah, that's how it's done

Comment: @Masoman Do you have some routing getting in the way maybe?

Comment: @DamienPirsy According to [CodeIgniter's](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) manual, `echo form_open('email/send');` would create a form that points to your base URL plus the "email/send" URI segments; `<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/email/send" />`

Comment: Indeed, and OP's using `book/book_validation`, and he has a controller named `book` and a method named `book_validation`. I don't see what you are considering it wrong

Comment: yes the controller is book the book_validation is the method name.

Comment: Hi Damien, what do you mean by routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function that need to edit:

```
public function insert() {
    $newRow = array("isbn" => $this->input->post('isbn'),
         "author" => $this->input->post('author'),
         "price" => $this->input->post('price'),
         "title" => $this->input->post('title'),
    );

    $this->model_books->insert1($newRow); // NOT get_db, but model_books
    echo "Item added ";
```

}

Everything else is Okey. I test it!

Comment: I tried that it still did not work,  $this->model_books->insert1($newRow);

Comment: I think this is a routing problem, is there something I have to do in my config files

Comment: ok, that worked, I had to put $this->model_books->insert1($newRow)